# Gridview colspan of footer button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that currently looks like this:
[image: Gridview]

I would like to make the cell with the button that says add new row to span the 2 columns of the buttons above it.

Also I would like to add text boxes on the other 4 columns and effectively make that row an "add user row" I'm a beginner and still experimenting, detailed explanations would be very helpful.

this is the html code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <header class="grid_9">פאנל מנהל</header>
    <div class="grid_9 block_head">
        טבלת משתמשים
    </div>
    <div class="block grid_9" id="user_block" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gdview" OnRowEditing="gdview_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="Grid" OnRowUpdating="gdview_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gdview_RowCancelingEdit"
            runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="tableheader" OnRowDeleting="gdview_RowDeleting" OnRowCreated="RowCreated"
            ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="מספר מזהה" DataField="id" ReadOnly></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="שם משתמש" DataField="username"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="סיסמא" DataField="password"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="אימייל" DataField="email"></asp:BoundField>

                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" CancelText="בטל" UpdateText="עדכן" EditText="ערוך"></asp:CommandField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdel" runat="server" Text="מחק" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This might help someone. The solution on below link worked for me:
https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/544063/HowplustoplusMergepluscellsplusinplusAsp-netplusGr#answer1

Snippet from the link:

```
gvitems.FooterRow.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 7;
gvitems.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(1);
gvitems.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(2);
gvitems.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(3);
gvitems.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(4);
gvitems.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(5);
gvitems.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(6);
```

Comment: This is good but it has a problem. When you remove cell of index 1, all other cells after that one change their index to their previous index - 1. So when you remove the cell of index 2 you are actually skipping the cell that used to be of index 2 which is now of index 1, and instead you are deleting the cell that used to be index 3 which is now 2. At some point  you will run out of cells and you will get an index violation (if you only have 7 cells). The correct way to do it is to reverse the order in which you remove the cells and start with cell of index 6 then 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1.

Comment: Joe Salazar, really helped me this thank you